# FlatMap or For-comprehension on a Nested Options Monad

Tags: scala, monads, flatmap

Can someone help me convert this to a flatMap or for-comprehension? I know how to handle more trivial scenarios of nested option.

```
    case class Person(name: String, signficantOther: Option[String])
    val nightclubPeoples : Option[Seq[Person]] = ???

    def significantOthers(nightClubPeoples : Option[Seq[Person]]) : List[String] = {
      nightclubPeoples match {
        case Some(x) => x map { y : Person => 
          y.significantOther match {
            case Some(z) => z
            case None => "No Signficant Other"
          }
        }.toList
        case None => Nil
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a fold:

```
nightclubPeoples.fold[List[String]](Nil)(_.flatMap(_.signficantOther)(collection.breakOut))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sascha Kolberg's answer is a, as I think, better solution(**just omit the case when signficantOther is empty, i.e "No Signficant Other" will not in the result List**) for your question, however since 
you demand "convert this to a flatMap or for-comprehension", so the code is as follows.

```
case class Person(name: String, signficantOther: Option[String])
val nightClubPeopleOpt : Option[Seq[Person]] = Some(Person("name", Some("1")) :: Person("name1", None) :: Nil)

def significantOthers(nightClubPeopleOpt : Option[Seq[Person]]) = {
    for {
        nightClubPeople <- nightClubPeopleOpt
    } yield {
        // scenario 1
        // if signficantOther is empty, then it should be ignored
        // Answer -> List(1)
        nightClubPeople.flatMap(_.signficantOther).toList

        // scenario 2
        // if signficantOther is empty, then we use the default "No Signficant Other"
        // Answer -> List(1, No Signficant Other)
        nightClubPeople.map { nightClubPerson =>
            nightClubPerson.signficantOther.getOrElse("No Signficant Other")
        }.toList
    }
}.getOrElse(Nil)


println(significantOthers(nightClubPeopleOpt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
nightclubPeoples.toSeq.flatMap(_.map(_.signficantOther.getOrElse("No Signficant Other")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively readable direct transformation would be:

```
def significantOthers(nightClubPeoples : Option[Seq[Person]]): List[String] = {
  for {
    nightClubPeoples <- nightClubPeoples.toList
    person <- nightClubPeoples
  } yield person.significantOther.getOrElse("No Significant Other")
}
```

The thing to note here is that we convert `nightClubPeoples` to a list up front, allowing us to use a for comprehension all along.

However, I doubt you really want to have "No Significant Other" appear in your list when `signficantOther` is `None`. Rather, it should be ignored, which would give the even simpler:

```
def significantOthers(nightClubPeoples : Option[Seq[Person]]): List[String] = {
  for {
    nightClubPeoples <- nightClubPeoples.toList
    person <- nightClubPeoples
    significantOther <- person.significantOther
  } yield significantOther
}
```